# Django URL Conf unable to find javascript file

Tags: django

I am learning Django and as an example I am trying to implement a small site that serves static pages. I  am using django.contrib.flatpages app for the same. As part of this, I have a javascript file located in a directory. I am referencing this javascript file in my html page. Accordingly, I have configured the URL pattern in my project's URL Conf file as follows:

```
url(r'^tinymce/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document-root':'C:/RAKESH/djangowork/cms/cms/templates/admin/flatpages/flatpage/tinymce'}),
```

But when I try to load the html page, the javascript file doesn't seem to be loaded. The following is the referencing code in my html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
selector:'textarea'
});
</script>
```

Can someone help me fix this problem?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add an extra URLconf for that! Use the standard way in Django to serve static (non-cms-editable) files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Place the *tinymce* folder inside a *static* folder in your app folder, then use in your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" %}"></script>
```